# to emanate from vs to stem from

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Are the words *to emanate from* and *to stem from* synonym in the following sense? Do you think I can swap with each other without changing the meaning of the following sentences ?

1 (Of a feeling, quality, or sensation) issue or spread out from (a source): warmth emanated from the fireplace she felt an undeniable charm emanating from him

1.1 Originate from; be produced by: the proposals emanated from a committee
More example sentences

1.2 [with object] Give out or emit (a feeling, quality, or sensation): he emanated a powerful brooding air

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/emanate

---

[no object] (stem from) Originate in or be caused by: many of the universities' problems stem from rapid expansion

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stem

Comment: The two words have identifiably different "figurative" connotations. Etymologically, ***emanate*** relates to ***flow** [out]*, so it often has implications of (covertly, unwantedly) *seeping* out. But ***stem*** obviously relates to (purposeful, forceful) ***growth***. Also, as you've obviously noted, the "object" for transitive *emanate* is *something given/coming out*, but for *stem* it's *something prevented from coming out*.

Comment: Consider that an odor emanates from  a flower while a flower stems from it's plant.

Comment: Note also that in the examples provided, "emanate" is used with things which radiate (or seep, as FunbleFingers puts it) outward -- warmth in the first, sound, information, or knowledge in the second, and the "feel" of the room in the third.  All these producers act as a central hub, broadcasting that which is emanated in all directions.

In the stem example, it's a more linear, cause-and-effect relationship.  Many problems, yes, but when investigating them, you consider one problem at a time, and investigate it's source; in the same way, you consider a flower and find it's stem.

Comment: @Mrt - Thanks for including the research you did.  It's a little hard to read as you posted it, though, for example "More example sentences"!  Could you clean it up a little?  There's an 'edit' button just under your post.

Comment: "to stem from" as in "X stemmed from Y" typically refers to Y as a *cause*:   *His pulmonary disease stemmed from years of smoking cigarettes.*  We wouldn't say "Proposals stemmed from the committee".  Some people would even say "His breathing problems *grew out of* years of smoking cigarettes".

Answer (score 0):

*Emanate* - is a word which implies rays, radiating out in any or all directions often many of them all at the same time - for example the rays of the sun.

*Stem* - is a word which is coming from plants and implies branching out. There might be one stem, and then another stem branches out from it, and then another one or two branches out from that.

Emanate, then implies energies coming out in various multiple directions - it also has a sense of a blob of light growing or diffusing out - in other words, the shape and the style of the energy coming out is diffuse and multidirectional.

Stem - is more specific, implying that energies are growing out from one place and then potentially branching out and becoming more.

So, one would choose to use these words depending on what one wants to express, and here are a few examples:

- The rays of light emanate from a lamp in the corner of the room and their ability to do so, stems from the electricity that they're plugged into.
- The wisdom of Einstein emanates from his ability to consider information holistically.
- Picasso's ability stems from the influence of his father, and from the time that he spent studying in the institute.
- Picasso's influence emanates into the world of Art, and the work of many artists stem from his creations and Innovations.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emanate